# Bash while loop search and replace using sed

Tags: shell-script, sed, array

I have a problem with my following script (this is the relevant part of it):

```
#!/bin/bash

OLD=(
"_MAIN1_"
"_MAIN2_"
)

NEW=(
"#111"
"#222"
)

length=${#OLD[*]}

i=0

while (( i < length ))
do
  sed -e "s/${OLD[$i]}/${NEW[$i]}/g" oldfile.txt > newfile.txt

  #sed -e 's/_MAIN1_/#111/g' oldfile.txt > newfile.txt  # this works

  # Another way that does not work
  #sed -e 's/'"${OLD[$i]}"'/'"${NEW[$i]}"'/g' oldfile.txt > newfile.txt

  ((i++))
done

exit 0
```

My goal is to replace strings in a file and save it into a new one. The "old" and "new" strings are stored in an array.

I tried a lot of things and played around with single and double quotes - but nothing worked.
When I `echo` the variables I get the correct strings inside the loop. If explicit two strings are set in `sed` command it works fine for this.

The string patterns follow those in my example arrays ('new' contains the underscore "_" and 'old' contains the hashtag "#").

I'm running bash on a Ubuntu 16.04 box.

Thank you very much!

Comment: *The string patterns follow those in my example arrays ('new' contains the underscore "_" and 'old' contains the hashtag "#").*  Typo?

Comment: You are not moving the edited file newfile.txt back to oldfile.txt, due to which all your edits are lost. newfile.txt would contain only the last edit at the end of the while loop. you should really be using the `-i` option in sed or `mv` newfile.txt -> oldfile.txt after every sed operation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a `sed` script that does all the substitutions, and then apply that `sed` script to your file.

```
for (( i=0; i<${#OLD[@]}; ++i )); do
        printf 's/%s/%s/g\n' "${OLD[$i]}" "${NEW[$i]}"
done >script.sed

sed -f script.sed inputfile >outputfile && mv outptufile inputfile && rm script.sed
```

This way you limit the number of times that you need to parse the input file to one.

For the given data in `OLD` and `NEW` the `sed` script will be generated as

```
s/_MAIN1_/#111/g
s/_MAIN2_/#222/g
```

Comment: This is a very elegant way - especially when the array contains a lot of entries.

Answer (score 0):

Your entire script (which doesn't work) can be replaced with the single line:

```
sed 's/_MAIN\([12]\)_/#\1\1\1/g' oldfile.txt > newfile.txt
```

Or, more readably but equivalently:

```
sed 's/_MAIN1_/#111/g;s/_MAIN2_/#222/g' oldfile.txt > newfile.txt
```

There are several dozen other ways to accomplish this, depending on your *actual* use case (e.g., where the data comes from, what the values really look like, what you are trying to do with the data, etc.).

Comment: The original array contains ~30 entries. That is why I use a loop. For my two example entries you are right. Thank you anyway!

Comment: @mazienho so, write a Sed script file.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to [Rakesh Sharma](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/218374/rakesh-sharma)'s comment I could solve this by using the `-i` flag in sed command. Before the loop the original file is backuped:

```
cp oldfile.txt oldfile.backup
while (( i < length ))
do
  sed -i -e 's/'"${OLD[$i]}"'/'"${NEW[$i]}"'/g' oldfile.txt
  ((i++))
done
```

The next time I will use Perl for string manipulations.

***Edit:*** Added `((i++))` to prevent an infinite loop (Thanks to [Kusalananda](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/116858/kusalananda)'s comment).

Comment: The variable `i` is never changed in the loop. This is an infinite loop.